# Issue with isometric view in Spritekit, Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tile, isometric

I'm trying to learn how to make an isometric view in Spritekit with Swift. I'm following several tutorials (or articles) on how to achieve an isometric view, however the code doesn't seem to be working for me -- I wonder if this may be because in Spritekit the coordinate system ranges from -240 to 240 and -160 to 160 in a 480x320 workspace. If so, I'm not sure at all how to correct for it.

This is my code:

```
var textures:[SKTexture] = [SKTexture(imageNamed: "Tile 3"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "Cliff test"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "Cliff test"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "Tile 3_test")]
var points:[CGPoint] = [CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(1, 0), CGPointMake(0, 1), CGPointMake(1, 1)]
var sprites:[SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode]()
let degrees:CGFloat = 45
var spriteSize:CGFloat = 50
var spriteSizeHalf:CGFloat = 25

for var i = 0; i < points.count; i++ {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: textures[i], color: nil, size: CGSizeMake(spriteSize, spriteSize))
    let label = SKLabelNode(text: "\(i)")
    sprite.addChild(label)

    let x = points[i].x
    let y = points[i].y

    //sprite.position = CGPointMake(x*spriteSize, y*spriteSize)

    sprites.append(sprite)
    main.addChild(sprite)

    //convert to Iso

    var isoPoint = CGPointMake(x-y, (x+y)/2)
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(isoPoint.x*spriteSize, isoPoint.y*spriteSize)
    sprite.zRotation = degrees*CGFloat((M_PI / 180.00))
}
```

And this is the result:

[photo http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3776/FbBycM.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3776/FbBycM.png)

Any thoughts on this?